# unable to get snapshotAvailableSpace of a softlayer endurance storage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am looking for *"space left"* from the *"total space reserved for snapshots"* on a endurance storage volume. I tried the following, but snapshotSpaceAvailable property did not show up.

**REST CALL:**

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/VOULME-ID?objectMask=id;notes;nasType;capacityGb;snapshotCapacityGb;snapshotSpaceAvailable;snapshotCount
```

**O/P:**

```
<root><capacityGb>100</capacityGb><id>VOLUME-ID</id><nasType>ISCSI</nasType><notes>NotesOnStorageVolume</notes><snapshotCount>30</snapshotCount><snapshotCapacityGb>5</snapshotCapacityGb></root>
```

Am I missing something here? Please help me get the value for  snapshotSpaceAvailable for a storage volume. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to get **snapshotSpaceAvailable** value, due to this is deprecated, the [Control Portal](https://control.softlayer.com) calculates this value of **snapshotSizeBytes** property from each snapshot

> **snapshot space** = capacity - [snapshots].snapshotSizeBytes

Here a rest request to get snapshots.snapshotSizeBytes:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/VOULME-ID?objectMask=id;notes;nasType;capacityGb;snapshotCapacityGb;snapshotCount;snapshots.snapshotSizeBytes

Method: Get
```

This task would be easy using a programing language, to see which are supported by SoftLayer:

- [SoftLayer Development Network](http://sldn.softlayer.com/)